# Can I copy some References of a project and paste it to another project's references in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference

I have seen this feature when I was watching Summer Of NHibernate tutorial videos; is it possible to copy some of of the references of a project in the solution and paste them into another project's references folder in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [**PowerCommands**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) for doing it.

[image: Copy References / Past References]

([see also Sara Ford's Blog](http://saraford.net/2010/09/07/power-commands-for-visual-studio-2010-extension-8/))

Comment: For VS2012 and 2013, this command is available in Productivity Power Tools, links: [2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) & [2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

Answer (score 9):

project files are just xml files. you can open them in a text editor and carefully copy the references.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) extension which doesn't suffer from errors affecting PowerCommands when pasting references.