# Copy an existing service reference from one project to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service-reference

I found a way to copy a DLL reference from one project to another using VS Power Tools. Apparently it can't copy service references. Is there a way to do this manually?

The problem is that we cannot access the service right now. So we have to build the code without being able to add the service reference conventionally.

Comment: Think you have to add this via Refernces -> Add references

Comment: That's right, the problem is that we cannot access the service right now. So we have to build the code without being able to add the service reference conventionally. 

Please also note that Reference is different from Service Reference.

Comment: Take a look into the .csproj file with a text editor and search for the name of the service. Copy this xml node into your other project file and also copy the  mentioned files by using the file explorer. Than it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that but looks it seems to be the only way. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work when you copied manually?

Comment: I ended up looking for the old wsdl file to make this work. copying it manually would be my last resort.

Comment: Your question was answered on this page [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742334/is-it-possible-to-copy-paste-references-from-one-project-to-another-in-visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742334/is-it-possible-to-copy-paste-references-from-one-project-to-another-in-visual)